# How can I use I timer in my Blazor server app, to perform an action periodically?

Tags: c#, razor, timer, blazor-server-side

Hello I have a Blazor server app where some PLC variables are read from a remote production machine.
The code part that is connecting to the PLC and reading the datas is in a sourced service (PLCService.cs). The service is injected and called in a razor page.
If I trigger the reading manualy with a button, all the variables are read correctly. So far no problem. But I want that the variables are read every second from the remote machine's PLC. Therefore I have programmed a timer in the codebehind page of my razor page (not in the service), but the timer is not working. (The values are note read even once)
In the razor page there are also the variables that I read from the PLC, but for making it leaner I have just shown the counter value, that should count each second.

In my razor file:

```
@inject PLCService PLCService
<button @onclick="Read_CNC_Status">Read PLC Data</button>
<l>@counter_timer</l>  // Unfortunately the counter value is always "0"
```

In my razor.cs file:

```
using System.Timers;
public partial class Read_PLC_Data
{
    public int counter_timer=0; 
    System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public async void Read_CNC_Status()
    {
        PLCService.Connect_PLC(); // Connection code is in a sourced service
        Initialise_Timer1();
    }

    public void Initialise_Timer1()
    {            
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent1);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        counter_timer = 0;
    }

    public void OnTimedEvent1(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        PLCService.Read_PLC_Data();            
        counter_CNC_status += 1;  // This counter is not counting !!!
        if(counter_timer >= 30)
        {
            counter_timer = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = false;

        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

}

Comment: Did u forget to start the timer?

Comment: i think that this is what you are looking for... Check the updated answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the periodic timer:

```
private readonly PeriodicTimer _periodicTimer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

public async void OnGet()
{
    while(await _periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
    {
        await ConnectPlc();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to go with your approach you should use `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` because Blazor would not recognize the state change and not refresh the UI

```
<h3>@_currentCount</h3>

@code {
    private int _currentCount;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       _timer = new();
       _timer.Interval = 1000;
       _timer.Elapsed += async (object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
       {
           _currentCount++;               
           await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
       };
       _timer.Enabled = true;
   }
}
```

Don't forget to invoke the `StateHasChanged` method

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to use the periodic timer that i initially suggest, you can use it this way:

First let's assume that you have a class that is responsible for PLC data and implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class PlcData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ILogger<PlcData> _logger;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int _counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get { return _counter; }
        set 
        { 
            if (_counter != value)
            {
                _counter = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Counter));
            }
        }
    }


    public PlcData(ILogger<PlcData> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task GetFromPlcAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Get new info: {c}", ++Counter);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then Create a background service

```
public class PlcService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly PlcData _plc;
    private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer;

    public PlcService(PlcData plc)
    {
        _plc = plc;
        _timer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while(await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken) 
            && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _plc.GetFromPlcAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In razor page your need to inject the `PlcData`

```
@inject PlcData plcData

<h3>@_currentCount</h3>

@code {
    private static int _currentCount;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        plcData.PropertyChanged += OnIncrement;
    }

    private async void OnIncrement(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentCount = plcData.Counter;
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

Also you need to add services to the container.

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<PlcService>();
...
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PlcData>();
```

Here is a typical `Program.cs` from .net6 Blazor-Server And that's it!

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Using System.Threading

```
@page "/"
@using System.Threading;

<h3>@_currentCount</h3>

@code {
    private int _currentCount;

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       var timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ =>
        {
            _currentCount++;
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }), null, 1000, 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but as soon as the first time the timer ticks, some values are coming, but the page is no reacting then. Unfortunately not working.

Comment: You need to have automatically updated data from plc in your web app?

Comment: Yes thats true. My PLC Data is read over a sourced service. As I said if I call the method in the service once, or repeatedly with a button manualy, everything is fine

Comment: Try the updated code please. The UI is fully responsibe

Comment: Sorry, one more question:  Regarding: "Also you need to add services to the container". Where do I have to register the services? When I try to add in Startup I get an error. Is the procedure for background service different then sourced service?

Comment: I updated the answer with an image of `Program.cs`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246804/discussion-between-ggeorge-and-mdarende).

Comment: Sorry but I cannot open your link from my Company Laptop. But I couldn't register the services as you have shown. I think because I user Blazor server .NET3. Is it not possible to do it with the scoped services? I tried with scoped services but couldnt bring it to work. Sorry that I am disturbing you so much :-(

Comment: Periodic Timer applies to .NET 6+

Comment: Last question: I want to concentrate again about your solution under UPDATE(1) with the InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged). Is this still a guilty solution?

Comment: I think that it's a decent solution. There are plenty examples that use this solution and with .net3.1 you can't use `PeriodicTimer`. The key difference between them is that the `PeriodicTimer` has almost no "losing" milliseconds, i mean that if you define every 1000ms then your method will delay almost 1000ms but with old `Timer` you will lose some ms in every iteration. I don't know if its clear to you.

Comment: I checked the last solution with .net 3.1 and works properly

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now with the "InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)" (Classic solution for 3.1) At the beginning I got an error: "The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state" But The reason was that I used an unneccesary "StatehasChanged()" in my method, that has to be executed periodically. When I deleted this, it worked lika a charm. I see that the most critical thing in Blazor is to setup the rendering correctly. Thank you so much for you great support.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you are calling the Read_CNC_Status() method. If you don't call it, then nothing you wrote about the timer is ever executed. You can call it in the component's OnAfterRender function (or in the constructor of your partial class).

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        Read_CNC_Status();
    }
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}
```

I ran the rest of the code and it works.

EDIT: It's not necessary, but I also recommend that you make sure the handler is not called again before the previous execution is finished (this could happen for example if Read_PLC_Data() is slow and takes more than the timer's Interval to complete). To do that, you can set the AutoReset property of your timer to false and manually restart the timer each time at the end of your handler, like this:

```
public async void Read_CNC_Status()
{
    PLCService.Connect_PLC(); // Connection code is in a sourced service
    Initialise_Timer1();
}

public void Initialise_Timer1()
{            
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent1);
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.AutoReset = false;
    counter_CNC_status = 0;
    timer1.Start();
}

public void OnTimedEvent1(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
          
    try
    {
        PLCService.Read_PLC_Data();      
        counter_CNC_status += 1;  // This counter is not counting !!!
    }
    finally
    {
        if(counter_CNC_status >= 30)
        {
            counter_CNC_status = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: I have forgotten to show the buttoni that is calling the function. It is not working although I press the button, but I will check your code.

Comment: Then another problem I see and didn't notice before is that you are incrementing a variable (counter_CNC_status) and displaying another one (counter_timer).

Answer (score -2):

The best approach for me is to use QUARTZ.NET